# Atribuir N (indefinidas) partes do input a N variáveis

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, split

Olá, qual seria a melhor forma de capturar um número indefinido de elementos **via um único input() do usuário** e atribuir cada uma delas a uma diferente variável?
Para um número definido de inputs (quando eu sei que o user irá entrar 3 ou 5 elementos separados por SPACE, por exemplo), seria fácil utilizando uma das opções abaixo:

```
x,y=map(int,input().split())
print(x)
print(y)
```

OU

```
x, y, z = input().split()
print(x, y, z)
```

Porém, ao meu ver nenhuma delas contempla um número indefinido de elementos em um input, certo? Pois em ambas ali eu já tinha definido que os inputs do usuário iriam para x e y (no caso de dois valores no input) ou pra x, y e z (no caso de três valores no input do user).

Usando essa solução de list comprehension abaixo eu consigo adicionar N (indefinidos) partes do input do usuário numa lista, porém não consigo atribuir cada um desses elementos da lista a uma variável diferente automaticamente.

```
x = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print("Number of list is: ", x)
```

A minha intenção seria algo do tipo:

> O usuário vai entrar com N (eu não sei quantos, pode ser só 1, ou 3 ou 5) números (ou strings) em um único input.
> Se ele digitar "1 3 5 7" esses valores vão ser atribuidos para: x1 = 1, x2 = 3, x3 = 5, x4 = 7.
> Caso o usuário digite "Laranja Cebola", esses valores serão atribuidos para x1 = "Laranja" e x2 = "Cebola".
> Caso o usuário digite N elementos, eu vou ter xN variáveis para receber os N elementos

Desculpa se ficou confuso ou muito enrolado, isso me parece algo muito simples, mas depois de quebrar bastante a cabeça tentando e pesquisando, não consegui encontrar algo preciso. Agradeço se puderem me ajudar nessa!

Comment: Não ficou confuso, mas é uma solução que não faz sentido. Sem saber quantas variáveis serão criadas, será impossível você acessá-las diretamente. Por exemplo, você não pode usar a "variável" `x10` pois não sabe se o usuário informou 10 valores ou mais. Daria erro de variável não definida. A melhor solução, dados os detalhes da pergunta, seria manter em uma lista mesmo.

Comment: Obter vários inputs numa linha não uma boa solução para a entrada de informações do usuário. Veja esse exemplo: https://ideone.com/iaUz8J o usuário digita alguns literais python numa linha e o programa separa essa linha entre os espaços e faz o parsing dos literais. Agora veja esse exemplo: https://ideone.com/K4HYhc é mesmo exemplo anterior porém o usuário digita errado um dos literais(`Fallse` com um `l` a mais) por conta de um erro de digitação a linha toda foi invalidada. O ideal é trabalhas as entradas individualmente.

Comment: @Woss Pois é, na minha cabeça eu até acho que faz um certo sentido você ter uma forma "automatizada" de poder atribuir um número indefinido de valores a indefinidas variáveis conforme a quantidade de itens no input; mas nem sempre o que faz sentido na cabeça acaba se traduzindo em algo viável pra programação né. E inclusive sou novo em programação, então ainda não tenho muito claro/definido o que é viável direito, só o tempo pra ajudar nessa  :) Valeu pela resposta

Comment: @AugustoVasques Apesar de ser inexperiente em programação, eu confesso que concordo contigo sobre obter vários valores em um único input não parecer ser a solução mais confiável/adequada. Eu fiquei preso nessa dúvida que decidi perguntar pois estou realizando vários problemas do Beecrowd (antigo URI), e vários problemas de lá pede que as informações sejam obtidas num único input.  Baseado nesses desafios pedindo dessa forma é que eu acreditei que isso fosse algo meio 'trivial' e eu não estava conseguindo enxergar. Valeu pelo retorno

Comment: No caso do beecrowd, **geralmente** eles dizem quantos valores têm, então daria pra usar as primeiras opções que vc colocou. Mas se vc não sabe quantos terá, fique com a lista mesmo, é o mais simples e direto. Abaixo sugeriram usar `globals`, mas apesar de "funcionar" não é a melhor opção, pois além de poluir o escopo global, ainda deixa desnecessariamente mais complicado. Fique com a lista, ela serve pra isso (ter N valores, com N podendo ser variável e só conhecido em tempo de execução)

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que desenvolvi um codigo que possa atender as suas necessidades.

```py
x = 1
print('Escreva as variaveis que quer salvar, caso queria pausar digite 0')
while True:
    globals()[f"variable{x}"] = c = input('Digite uma variavel: ').strip()
    if c == '0':
        break
    x += 1
for z in range(1, x):
    print(f'Variavel {z} = {globals()[f"variable{z}"]}')
```

O programa irá salvar continuamente os valores digitados pelo usuário e irá interroper somente se ele digitar 0, as variaveis são criadas automaticamente de variable1, variable2, variable 3 até quantas o usuário digitar.

no laço for eu estou demonstrando que as variaveis existem e tem todos os seus valores salvos.

Pensando melhor, acredito que cheguei em um codigo que atende perfeitamente ao que você pediu.

```py
x = input('Digite as variaveis separadas por espaços: ').strip().split()
for z in range(0, len(x)):
    print(x[z])
    globals()[f"variable{z}"] = x[z]
for r in range(0, len(x)):
    print(f'Variavel {r} = {globals()[f"variable{r}"]}')
```

Nessa versão do codgio o usuário pode digitar Lucas 2 Arthur 4 65 ...
e o computador irá salvar cada uma dessas informações em variaveis separadas.

Answer (score -3):

Simples,

Tu precisa criar uma coleção de objetos,

Primeiro receba em um array chamado x os dados do formulario, ja quebrando-os como você fez, para depois fazer um foreach preenchendo um novo array (coleção de objetos)

Preencha o array de coleção de objetos com o objeto abstraído como por exemplo o objeto "Variavel".

```
x = split()
array = [];
foreach x as elemento{
obj = new Variavel()
obj.nome = elemento

array[] = obj;
}
```